# Execute event if not button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="panel"> <h4>Title <button>Show something</button> </h4>  </div>
```

And how to change the JS code to execute an event if someone click the class panel ,but not button ?

Was trying to do:

```
$( ".panel:not(button)" ).on( "click",
```

But it doesn't work.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: in your click handler, capture the event. You can then use this to find the current target, and decide not to call the click if the target was a button.   See https://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an event listener on the `panel` class.

```
$('.panel').on('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

Also, you will have to add an event listener on the button and tell it not to trigger any events for it's parents.

```
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

1. Hook `click` on the `button` and stop propagation:

   ```
   $(".panel").on("click", function() {
       // Do the thing
   });
   $(".panel button").on("click", function(e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
   });
   ```
2. Check in the `click` if it passed through a button en route:

   ```
   $(".panel").on("click", function(e) {
       var elm = e.target;
       while (elm !== this) {
          if (elm.tagName === "BUTTON") {
              return;
          }
       }
       // Do the thing
   });
   ```

   Actually, since it's a `button`, the handler for #2 can be simpler:

   ```
   $(".panel").on("click", function(e) {
       if (!$(e.target).closest("button").length) {
           // Do the thing
       }
   });
   ```

   ...since we know the `.panel` won't be inside a `button` (as that would mean the `.panel`'s `button` was inside another button, which is invalid).

Answer (score 0):

Check for target to click.

```js
$( ".panel" ).on( "click",function(e){
  if($(e.target).is('button')){
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        }
    alert('clicked');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel"><h4>Title <button class='clsButton'>Show something</button> </h4>  </div>
```